# Top 2 of each group ordered SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 8 records

```
Name        Value  Product
--------------------------
Abraham       4        A
Lincoln       6        B
Abraham       4        C
Lincoln       2        D
Lincoln       3        E
Lincoln       2        F
Abraham       1        G
Abraham       9        H
```

Abraham has 4 records and Lincoln too.

I need, from the SQL, the top 2 values from Abraham and the top 2 values from Lincoln

I've tried:

```
SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES 
    NAME,
    VALUE,
    PRODUCT
FROM
    blabla
JOIN
    blabla...
ORDER BY 
    NAME
```

This takes 2 of each name, but not the most valuables, because I'm not setting a VALUE order by desc.

But I can't put the VALUE order by desc because of the top with ties..

What I need is something like making my TOP WITH TIES works only for ORDER BY NAME (if there is a way to do this, like restricting the top with ties to the first order by), but I need only the 2 max values of them.

The final result I need:

```
Abraham       9        H   
Abraham       4        C
Lincoln       6        B
Lincoln       3        E
```

PS: This is only a simulation of what I want, the original query has like over 100 lines with union and stuff, so i think it was better to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ROW_NUMBER and partitioning.

```
select Name
    , Value
    , Product
from
(
    select Name
        , Value
        , Product
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by value desc)
    from SomeTable
) x
where x.RowNum <= 2
order by x.Name
    , x.Value desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP` and `ORDER BY`. You start with the list of names and call a "*function*" that returns the `TOP` for each name.

```
SELECT
    N.Name,
    V.Value,
    V.Product
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Y.Name FROM YourTable AS Y) AS N
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES
            P.Value,
            P.Product
        FROM
            YourTable AS P
        WHERE
            N.Name = P.Name
        ORDER BY
            P.Value DESC
    ) AS V
```

Keep in mind that using `WITH TIES` can make the `TOP` return more than the supplied number of rows (2 for your example), in case that there are ties of values.

If you need to show names which don't have products (in this example it won't work because both come from the same table), you can switch the `CROSS APPLY` for an `OUTER APPLY`, which behaves similar to a `LEFT JOIN` as it will return `NULL` values (but not 2 rows!).